# jQuery ToggleClass to Full Screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use jQuery's toggleClass() to click on a div and have that div expand to a height and width of 100% (in other words, full screen). I thought this would be easy, but for some reason, I'm struggling. Must be tired this morning... The following code toggles to 100% height and width, but it doesn't toggle back to the original size.

HTML

```
<div class="s3div1" id="s3div1"></div>
```

JS

```
$("div#s3div1").dblclick(function (event) {
    $(".s3div1").toggleClass("overlay").toggleClass("s3div1");
    });
```

CSS

```
.overlay {  
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:1000;
}

.s3div1 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 0px;
    right: 25px;
    height: 550px;
    width: 225px;
    border: 5px solid white;
    border-radius: 25px;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 8%;      
}

#s3div1 {
    background-image: url('assets/volcano3.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are referencing by class name instead of the object to which the double-click event refers.

Instead use the value of $(this) which is the target object of the double-click (wrapped in a JQuery object for easier use):

```
$("div#s3div1").dblclick(function (event) {
   $(this).toggleClass("overlay").toggleClass("s3div1");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean:

```
$("#s3div1").toggleClass("overlay").toggleClass("s3div1");
   ^-- # instead of .
```

Once you toggle the class `.s3div1` wont match anymore so the 2nd time you dblclick nothing happens.

Go talk a walk, drink some coffee, eat an orange.